# Using "lacking" without specifying an exact area

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

There is an adjective "lacking" which could be used in a form like "lacking in sth", e.g.

> He is lacking in confidence.

Is it possible to use it without providing specific area, e.g.

> He is lacking.

Meaning that he is just lacking in general, missing something that I cannot define right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use it that way, but if you do, you should be prepared for a question, like
Lacking in what way? or
What does he lack?

It would be like saying "He's not good enough." or "He just won't do.", without saying why.